# how to display multiple modals as you click a button in each consecutive modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to ajax multiple dialogs onto the page and then display the first and subsequent dialogs when the user clicks on the okay button within each dialog.  i've got pretty close but it doesn't quite work.  The problem i have is that i'm not sure how to close the clicked modal and then display the next modal in sequence.  any help much appreciated!???

thanks,

**mark up**

```
<div class="mymodal" style="display: none">
    <!-- inject modal content into here -->
</div>
```

**javascript code**

```
(function(ns) {

  var modalArray = [];

  ns.calculateWhatModalsWeNeed = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl,
        cache: 'testurl',
        data: myData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            // based on the response an array is built up
            // i.e.
            modalArray.push('modal1');
            modalArray.push('modal2');

            ns.loadModals(modalArray, ns.showModal());  
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });

  };

  ns.loadModals = function(modalsToShow, callback) {

    // call and load the modal mark up into the DOM
    for (var i = 0; i < modalsToShow.length; i++) {

        var successCallBack = function (html) {
            $('.mymodal').append(html);
        };

        // Load modal window onto page
        var modalUrl = 'myurl' + modalsToShow[i];

        // ajax command to call the mvc controller
        // the modalsToShow array are the view names
        // i.e. 'myurl' + '/' + modalsToShow[i];

        ajaxcommand.get(...);
    }

    if (callback && typeof (callback) === 'function') callback();

};

ns.showModal = function () {

    // this is the problem i think - how to 
    // trigger each modal here as you click okay on each one..?

    $('mymodal:first').dialog({
        width: 633,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true
    });
};

})(namespace('stackoverflow.problem'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the **[close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)** event for the dialog.

```
$('mymodal:first').dialog({
    width: 633,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    modal: true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // do something...    
    }
});
```

You can also bind event listener like so:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

On a side note, you are missing a `.` before your `mymodal` class.

Comment: so the rest of the code looks okay?  Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I'm not quite sure on what you are intending on, but if you want sort of an infinite sequence of modals, you can simply do your ajax call on close event and then trigger the open with the success callback from the ajax request. If you need to stop at some point, you can check for something before opening the modals. Hope that helps.

Comment: i call a service that returns what modals I need to display, i.e. car.cshtml, plane.cshtml, ship.cshtml etc..  the return from the service can be any of these or all of them.  then i need to actually call the urls for these modals to inject the modals onto the page.  after this i then need to show the first modal, i.e. car.cshtml.  the modal has an okay button on it.  when the user clicks on the okay button it needs to close and then show the next modal, i.e. car.cshtml.  hope that helps

Comment: I have tried the close event but I'm not sure how to trigger the closing of the first modal correctly?  My attempts close all modals